# Enabling method chains in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype, method-chaining

This question mostly is about javascript best practices when injecting behavior into objects. I have a bunch of small objects that follow some interfaces:

```
export interface Semigroup<A> {
    append(l: A, r: A): A;
}

export interface Monoid<A> extends Semigroup<A> {
    empty(): A;
}
```

And a bunch of combinator methods that work with those objects. Using those as a method chain is much nicer.

To make a bunch of static methods available on a bunch of objects I see two obvious solutions:

- Create a prototype object and set that on all base types
- Wrap all base types in an adapter that forwards the basic behavior

I currently use the latter one:

```
class AMonoid<A> implements Monoid<A> {
    private theMonoid: Monoid<A>;
    constructor(theMonoid: Monoid<A>) {
        this.theMonoid = theMonoid;
    }
    append(l: A, r: A): A {
        return this.theMonoid.append(l, r);
    }
    empty(): A {
        return this.theMonoid.empty();
    }
    liftMap(): AMonoid<Map<any, A>> {
        return liftMonoidToMap(this);
    }
    fold(): F.AFold<A, A> {
        return foldMonoid(this);
    }
}

export const sum = new AMonoid({
    empty: () => 0,
    append: (l,r) => l+r
});
```

The prototype solution seem more javascript-y but I am worried about unintended side effects. What happens if the wrapped object has one of the utility methods by accident? Is it possible to make typescript create a type error in this case? Do private methods/properties play nice with this?

Comment: I don't follow the question. What's M? How do the liftMap, fold etc methods relate to the two interfaces you've defined?

Comment: If you're using algebraic types like Monoids, you should know about functors. You can easily just use a simple identity functor to do a chain of `.map` transformations that will interact with the value held inside.

Comment: @matthelliwell Thanks for your answer, I updated the example to make it more obvious what I am asking about.

Comment: I think you need to decide what language you want to work in.  This code is TypeScript.  And in TS (as I understand it; I'm no expert) this style here probably comes across as more natural.  But in Javascript, the prototype chain or a mixin is probably more idiomatic.  Overwriting methods is probably a concern no matter how you do it, but so long as the overriding keeps the same signature, I don't think it matters; it can even be useful: while you can define `lift` using `ap` and `map` for instance, your type might have a much more efficient implementation.

Comment: As @VLAZ says, look how a functor is implemented in Typescript and extend that approach. But basically I'd do it using a Class rather than changing prototypes.

Comment: What do you mean by "*What happens if the wrapped object has one of the utility methods by accident?*" - are you talking about `theMonoid`? If so, why would you care if it had extra methods that you are not using?